# VSCode mysterious command prompt window apearing in Debug Console

Tags: visual-studio-code

I seem to be pressing some keyboard shortcut that is opening a command prompt in the Debug console. I don't know what it is so can't find how to close it. Sometimes it covers half the debug console.

How do I close it? So far only restarting VSCode seems to get rid of it but that's inconvenient since I lose all my undo history that way, and it also closes the open simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This console is inactive when you not debug something. Press `Ctrl+Shift+Y` to close it.

About the arrow on your screenshot: you can write commands to this prompt during debugging process. For example for gdb use `-exec` and type command you need.